# C# XML config file custom section always null

Tags: xml, configuration-files

Working on a VSTO Outlook addin. I need to store configuration parameters in an XML file. I am struggling with some basic config file loading issue. I would appreciate a fresh view:

customConfiguration.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

  <configSections>
      <section name="CDSSettings"  type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler" />
  </configSections>

  <CDSSettings>
    <add key="APIusername" value="myUser" />
    <add key="APIpassword" value="myPassword" />
  </CDSSettings>

    <appSettings>
      <add key="logLevel" value="0" /> 
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Code

```
ExeConfigurationFileMap map = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
map.ExeConfigFilename = "customConfiguration.xml";
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(map, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

AppSettingsSection appSettingsSection = (config.GetSection("appSettings") as AppSettingsSection);
// --> All ok

ConfigurationSection CDSSettings = (ConfigurationSection)config.GetSection("CDSSettings");
// --> How to get the APIusername key?
```

Any chance I can avoid an XML parser or SectionInformation.GetRawXml()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't explain why `ConfigurationManager.GetSection` and `config.GetSection` returns different results `object`, that can be converted to `NameValueCollection` in first case, and section that is `DefaultSection in second`.

I would suggest to create a custom section and use it:

```
public class CDSSettings : ConfigurationSection
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("MyValues")]
    public KeyValueConfigurationCollection MyValues
    {
        get { return (KeyValueConfigurationCollection) this["MyValues"]; }
        set { this["MyValues"] = value; }
    }
}
```

and config will looks like

```
<section name="CDSSettings"  type="UCAddin.CDSSettings, UCAddin" />
...
<CDSSettings>
  <MyValues>
    <add key="APIusername" value="myUser" />
    <add key="APIpassword" value="myPassword" />
  </MyValues>
</CDSSettings>
```

Retrieve code:

```
var CDSSettings = (CDSSettings)config.GetSection("CDSSettings");
```

**More**
In case of custom section you can also specify different types of fields e.g.
you can have separate named element:

```
public class Credentials : ConfigurationElement
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("login")]
    public string Login
    {
        get { return (string)this["login"]; }
        set { this["login"] = value; }
    }
}
```

with named proerties

```
[ConfigurationProperty("credentials")]
public Credentials Credentials
{
    get { return (Credentials) this["credentials"]; }
    set { this["credentials"] = value; }
}
```

and config will looks like

```
<CDSSettings>
  <credentials login="testlogin" />
</CDSSettings>
```

Check [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx) for more possibilities

**As AppSettings**
You can register property as default collection

```
public class CDSSettings : ConfigurationSection
{

    [ConfigurationProperty("", IsDefaultCollection = true)]
    public KeyValueConfigurationCollection MyValues => 
                (KeyValueConfigurationCollection) this[string.Empty];
}
```

and have parameters as in App Settings

```
<CDSSettings>
  <add key="login" value="User" />
</CDSSettings>
```

But in code those data will be accessible from the property (if you'll not implement indexer in the class)

```
var settings = (CDSSettings)config.GetSection("CDSSettings");
settings.MyValues
```

Comment: Thanks, looks elegant. the code is raising a  "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Configuration.DefaultSection' to type 'UCAddin.CDSSettings'." now but I assume that it should be fixable. Any chance I can skip the MyValues tag? I want the XML to be as clean as possible.

Comment: Sorry forgot to add changes in section registration. Add into the answer

Comment: Added other possible things

Comment: @Salim added one more block into the answer

Comment: Thanks ASpirin, the App Settings and default collection property approach seems exactly what I want. I can't however get your code sample to work. I will look at it deeper tonight and will feedback.

Comment: good, let. I have the code working in my test application. If you wouldn't come to a point, I can separate a code and send it to you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152084/discussion-between-aspirin-and-salim).